# How to write something in JTextArea and show it without pressing any button

Tags: java, swing, jframe, jtextarea

I have taken a text area on a jframe but I dont know how to write text for text area on the source  and I want to show message on the text area when I press a button from another jframe.
Suppose I clicked "Location" button on a jframe and the location will show in a text area on another jframe.

Answer (score 1):

Use a [Observer Pattern](http://www.oodesign.com/observer-pattern.html) to allow you class with the `JTextArea` to "obsever" changes or events from your other class.  This way you decouple your code and make it easier to manage and update.

You could make your own or re-use one of the listeners from Swing, such as `ActionListener` or `ChangeListener`